Portable implementation of computing high 64 bits in widening 128 bit multiplication
How could I implement signed and unsigned multiplication of two 64 bit numbers, widened into 128 bits, and discarding the low 64 bits, returning the high 64 bits? The multiplication must properly wrap according to twos complement, without exhibiting undefined behavior.
#include <stdint.h>

int64_t imul128hi(int64_t lhs, int64_t rhs);
uint64_t mul128hi(uint64_t lhs, uint64_t rhs);

Simple portable C with stdint.h is required, no unreasonable __builtin instrinsics. I am using this code as a stub in the output of a WASM JIT compiler. Don't use ((uint128_t)x * y) >> 64 please. The goal here is to emulate imul and mul instructions.
# printf '\x49\xf7\xe8' | ndisasm -b 64 -
00000000  49F7E8            imul r8
# printf '\x49\xf7\xe0' | ndisasm -b 64 -
00000000  49F7E0            mul r8


Add mov %rdx, %rax?

64*64 (to 128) arithmetic is well-documented and there are plenty of examples online. Once you have the 128-bit result, doing a shift on it should be rather trivial (and also with plenty of documentation and examples). What have you tried? What resources are you using?

Wasn't this exact question asked recently?

"The multiplication must properly wrap according to twos complement," is unclear.  There is no "wrapping" - all possible products are in range.

if you want your implementation to be portable you will need to be able to provide also unsigned by signed functions (mixed signedness)

Back to long-multiplication... with base 2^32
     a    b                  // a, b, c, and d are
x    c    d                  // 32-bit values (in a 64-bit variable)
-----------
    ad   bd                  // all numbers here are 64-bit values
ac  bc                       // "main" number in the low 32 bits
-----------                  // "carry" in the high 32 bits
ac ad+bc bd
|   |    \---- bits 0 to 31 (with carry in bits 32 to 63)
|   \--------- bits 32 to 63 (with carry in bits 64 to 95)
\------------- bits 64 to 95 (with carry in bits 96 to 127)

--
uint64_t mul128hi(uint64_t lhs, uint64_t rhs) {
    uint64_t bd = (lhs & 0xffffffff) * (rhs & 0xffffffff);
    uint64_t ad = (lhs >> 32) * (rhs & 0xffffffff);
    uint64_t bc = (lhs & 0xffffffff) * (rhs >> 32);
    uint64_t ac = (lhs >> 32) * (rhs >> 32);

    // correction by chux incorporated, thanks
    uint64_t mid_sum = bc + (bd >> 32);  // This never overflows.
    uint64_t carry = ad > UINT64_MAX - mid_sum ? 0x100000000: 0;
    uint64_t ad_plus_bc = ad + mid_sum; // ad + mid_sum may overflow.
    return ac + (ad_plus_bc >> 32) + carry;
}


Mathematically, the 64-bit, unsigned multiplicands A and B can be each be split into 2 32-bit values AH, AL, BH, BL such that

A = AH × 232 + AL
B = BH × 232 + BL

The 64-bit multiplication can then be expressed as:

A × B = (AH × 232 + AL) × (BH × 232 + BL).

Rearranging:

A × B = AH × BH × 264 + (AH × BL + AL × BH) × 232 + AL × BL

This is a 128-bit result, but we only want the upper 64-bits:

A × B / 264 = (AH × BH × 264 + (AH × BL + AL × BH) × 232 + AL × BL) / 264
A × B / 264 = AH × BH + (AH × BL + AL × BH) / 232 + AL × BL / 264
A × B / 264 = AH × BH + (AH × BL + AL × BH) / 232 + AL × BL / 232 / 232
A × B / 264 = AH × BH + (AH × BL + AL × BH + AL × BL / 232) / 232

Discarding the fractional part after division by 264 leaves:

⌊A × B / 264⌋ = AH × BH + ⌊(AH × BL + AL × BH + ⌊AL × BL / 232⌋) / 232⌋

This can be calculated using 64-bit multiplications, additions, and bit-shifts. However, the result of the addition AH × BL + AL × BH + ⌊AL × BL / 232⌋ may be 65 bits wide, that is 64 bits and 1 carry-out bit. Mathematically, the carry-out bit has value 264. This needs to be divided by 232 and added to the result:

Let X = AH × BL. Let Y = AL × BH. Let Z = ⌊AL × BL / 232⌋.
Let S = (X + Y + Z) mod 264.
Let C = 1 if S < X or S < Y, otherwise let C = 0.

Then:

⌊A × B / 264⌋ = AH × BH + C × 232 + ⌊S / 232⌋

See @chux's answer for the code (based on @pmg's answer with a bug-fix).
Worked example where arithmetic overflow occurs in the addition of X + Y + Z:

A = 0x80000001FFFFFFFE
B = 0x80000001FFFFFFFD
A × B = 0x80000001FFFFFFFE × 0x80000001FFFFFFFD = 0x40000002000000017FFFFFF600000006
⌊A × B / 264⌋ = ⌊0x40000002000000017FFFFFF600000006 / 264⌋ = 0x4000000200000001
AH = 0x80000001, AL = 0xFFFFFFFE
BH = 0x80000001, BL = 0xFFFFFFFD
AH × BH = 0x80000001 × 0x80000001 = 0x4000000100000001
X = AH × BL = 0x80000001 × 0xFFFFFFFD = 0x7FFFFFFF7FFFFFFD
Y = AL × BH = 0xFFFFFFFE × 0x80000001 = 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFE
AL × BL = 0xFFFFFFFE × 0xFFFFFFFD = 0xFFFFFFFB00000006
Z = ⌊AL × BL / 232⌋ = ⌊0xFFFFFFFB00000006 / 232⌋ = 0xFFFFFFFB
X + Y + Z = 0x7FFFFFFF7FFFFFFD + 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFE + 0xFFFFFFFB = 0x1000000007FFFFFF6 { N.B. overflows 64 bits }
S = (X + Y + Z) mod 264 = (0x1000000007FFFFFF6) mod 264 = 0x000000007FFFFFF6
C = 1 { because S < X or S < Y }
⌊S / 232⌋ = ⌊0x000000007FFFFFF6 / 232⌋ = 0
C × 232 = 1 × 232 = 0x0000000100000000
AH × BH + C × 232 + ⌊S / 232⌋ = 0x4000000100000001 + 0x0000000100000000 + 0 = 0x4000000200000001


@chux Thanks, it's unsigned multiplication so INT64_MAX is OK, but the addition may overflow for some larger values. For A=0x80000001FFFFFFFE, B=0x80000001FFFFFFFD, the addition of all three terms (0x7FFFFFFF7FFFFFFD + 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFE + 0xFFFFFFFB) will overflow, but the addition of the two largest terms will not overflow.

@chux I have applied your correction to the answer, using my values of A and B above in the worked example.

Ian Abbott, Oops, my comment should have been about UINT64_MAX - looks like you now addressed that.

Like @pmg with code correction.
uint64_t mul128hi(uint64_t lhs, uint64_t rhs) {
    uint64_t bd = (lhs & 0xffffffff) * (rhs & 0xffffffff);
    uint64_t ad = (lhs >> 32) * (rhs & 0xffffffff);
    uint64_t bc = (lhs & 0xffffffff) * (rhs >> 32);
    uint64_t ac = (lhs >> 32) * (rhs >> 32);

    uint64_t mid_sum = bc + (bd >> 32);  // This never overflows.
    uint64_t carry = ad > UINT64_MAX - mid_sum ? 0x100000000: 0;
    uint64_t ad_plus_bc = ad + mid_sum; // ad + mid_sum may overflow.
    return ac + (ad_plus_bc >> 32) + carry;             
}


Given:
#include <stdint.h>

typedef unsigned __int128 u128;

uint64_t
mul_1(uint64_t x,uint64_t y)
{
    u128 t = x;
    t *= y;
    return t >> 64;
}

Compiling with gcc -O3, the disassembly is:

orig.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <mul_1>:
   0:   48 89 f0                mov    %rsi,%rax
   3:   48 f7 e7                mul    %rdi
   6:   48 89 d0                mov    %rdx,%rax
   9:   c3                      retq

So, the compiler is smart enough to replace the shift with a mov.

I believe OP is trying to avoid 128-bit operations.

Please refer to my question.
